# Include a php file from functions.php only to homepage

Tags: php, functions

I'm re-developing a wordpress theme using sage them framework. I have this array in functions.php

```
$sage_includes = [
  'lib/assets.php',    // Scripts and stylesheets
  'lib/theme_options.php',    // Theme Options
  'lib/setup.php',     // Theme setup
  'lib/titles.php',    // Page titles
  'lib/wrapper.php',   // Theme wrapper class
  'lib/home_shortcodes.php', // Homeapage Shortcodes
  'lib/shortcodes.php' // Old Theme Shortcodes

];
```

which is loaded below

```
foreach ($sage_includes as $file) {
  if (!$filepath = locate_template($file)) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(__('Error locating %s for inclusion', 'sage'), $file), E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  require_once $filepath;
}
unset($file, $filepath);
```

Now I have home_shortcodes.php and shortcodes.php, I want the home_shortcodes.php to be loaded only on my front page / homepage how can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `is_home()` or `is_front_page()` to check the current page.

```
$sage_includes = [
    'lib/assets.php',    // Scripts and stylesheets
    'lib/theme_options.php',    // Theme Options
    'lib/setup.php',     // Theme setup
    'lib/titles.php',    // Page titles
    'lib/wrapper.php',   // Theme wrapper class
    'lib/shortcodes.php' // Old Theme Shortcodes

];
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
    $sage_includes[] = 'lib/home_shortcodes.php'; // Homeapage Shortcodes
}
```